# How to change the style of tab in segment control in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabs, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segment control where I'm displaying tabs. But I'm not able to edit the style of the tab in Xamarin Forms. **This is the UI I want**

[image]

This is how I want to display my tabs in the segment control. I'm able to change the tint color, background color, and text color but none of that will get me a tab in this style. **This is my current UI**

[image]

This is XAML code where I implemented the segment control

```
<controls:SegmentedControl  BackgroundColor="White" SelectedTextColor="Black" TintColor="#FFA500" x:Name="SegControl" ValueChanged="Handle_ValueChanged">
                <controls:SegmentedControl.Children>
                    <controls:SegmentedControlOption  Text="VENDOR NAME" />
                    <controls:SegmentedControlOption Text="PRODUCT/SERVICE" />
                </controls:SegmentedControl.Children>
            </controls:SegmentedControl>
            <StackLayout x:Name="SegContent" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Margin="0,30,0,0">
            <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".20,1,1,.1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">

                <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarStackLayoutStyle}" x:Name="stckNear">

                    <Image Margin="0,10,0,10" x:Name="imgNear" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarImageStyle}" />
                    <Label Text="Near" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarLabelStyle}"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarStackLayoutStyle}" x:Name="stckSearch">
                    <Image Margin="0,10,0,10" x:Name="imgSearch" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarImageStyle}" />
                    <Label Text="Search" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarLabelStyle}"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarStackLayoutStyle}" x:Name="stckCart">
                    <Image Margin="0,10,0,10" x:Name="imgCart" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarImageStyle}" />
                    <Label Text="Cart" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarLabelStyle}"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarStackLayoutStyle}" x:Name="stckAccount">
                    <Image Margin="0,10,0,10" x:Name="imgAccount" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarImageStyle}" />
                    <Label Text="Account" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarLabelStyle}"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
```

I'm not using any custom renderer for this segment control. Do I have to use a custom renderer for implementing the required UI? If yes how? Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this question for Tab UI or segmented control UI? If for segmented control what UI do you need?

Comment: @CGPA6.4 this is a question for segmented control UI.

Comment: Can you tell me how UI do you need? You said in question- _I'm not able to edit the style of the tab in Xamarin Forms_

Comment: @CGPA6.4 I want the UI like the first image as I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: I think this is not possible. You need to use tabs instead of segmented control.

Comment: @CGPA6.4 Is it possible to add a box view below the Vendor name and product/service which changes color on click?

Comment: @CGPA6.4 I just want a line below the vendor name and product/service instead of box.

Comment: @CGPA6.4 I know with the tabbed page it can be easily done but I won't be able to add the search bar at the top of the tab so that's why I used this segmented control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SegmentedControl is not a built in Xamarin.Forms control. There are a few libraries that offer a SegmentedControl, so it would help to know which one you are using.

That said, the library author who created that SegmentedControl also made the platform renderers and so the different look on iOS vs Android is a result of that.

You can, of course, create your own custom renderer, but then why use the library?

Easier to me would be to make a control using Xamarin Forms, for instance you can use a grid that has a first row of two labels ( or Buttons) and a second row of 2 [BoxViews](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/boxview) that can act as the underline (very short height). Then just add [TapGestureRecognizers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap) to each Label (or just use a Buttons and style as needed).

Here's an example using Buttons and BoxViews:

XAML:

```
    <Grid Padding="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="vBtn"
                Text="VENDOR NAME" Clicked="Handle_Clicked"
                TextColor="Black"
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                BorderColor="Transparent"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Button x:Name="pBtn"
                Text="PRODUCT/SERVICE" Clicked="Handle_Clicked"
                TextColor="Black"
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                BorderColor="Transparent"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="1" />
        <BoxView x:Name="vBox"
                 Color="#FFA500" HeightRequest="5"
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 Grid.Column="0"/>
        <BoxView x:Name="pBox"
                 Color="Silver" HeightRequest="5" 
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
    void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        if (btn.Text == "PRODUCT/SERVICE")
        {
            vBox.Color = Color.Silver;
            pBox.Color = Color.FromHex("#FFA500");
            // Do anything else you need to do when the PRODUCT/SERVICE is tapped
        }
        else
        {
            vBox.Color = Color.FromHex("#FFA500");
            pBox.Color = Color.Silver;
            // Do anything else you need to do when the VENDOR NAME is tapped
        }
    }
```

[image] [image]

No library or custom renderer needed.